# Vue crash when ssl is active

Tags: ssl, vue.js, webpack

I have a project that cointains a couples of vue components. The main file loads the components when are needed by lazy loading them.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const DateFiled = () => import('./components/DateField')
const ItemClone = () => import('./components/ItemClone')
...

Vue.component('date-field', DateFiled);
Vue.component('item-clone',  ItemClone);
...

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

This work on `development`, but on `production` it only work when the ssl is off. if i turn it on i get an error

```
mixed content the page at was loaded over https but requested an insecure...
```

The error show that it try to get the chunks from `http://localhostjs/js/chunks/0.bundle.js`, why this happens only when ssl is on?
how can i solve this?

i have tried to add the url in the webpack like this

```
mix.config.webpackConfig.output = {
    chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: process.env.APP_URL,
};
```

and have tried to set `APP_URL` to

```
APP_URL=https://example.com/
APP_URL=/
APP_URL=https://example.com/public/
```

But none of those worked. the server is `apache` on `centOs`

Comment: What server do you use to serve your application? Also, please provide an example value of `process.env.APP_URL`. No need to provide actual domain, the format is important.